# Docker "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

I'm new to Docker. I managed to build an image with the things I wanted (CentOS with Apache, PHP, MySQL, MailHog and supervisord.) It works fine.

Now, what I'm trying to do is turn my image (one container) into multiple images/containers: one for `web`, one for `db`, etc.

I managed to build those different images, but I'm having trouble linking `web` and `db` together via `docker-composer.yml`. Here is what I have:

```
web:
  container_name: centosweb
  image: fab/centosweb
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    # Single files
    - ./config/httpd.conf:/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    # Directories
    - ./vhosts:/var/www/html
    - /Users/fabien/Dropbox/AppData/XAMPP/web/bilingueanglais/public_html:/var/www/html/bilingueanglais
    - ./logs/apache:/etc/httpd/logs # This will include access_log(s) and error_log(s), including PHP errors.
  links:
    - db
db:
  container_name: centosdb
  image: fab/centosdb
  volumes:
    # Single files
    - ./config/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
    # Directories
    - ./mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
```

The output of `docker ps` is this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                  NAMES
95048de7a6c4        fab/centosweb       "supervisord -n"    14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       22/tcp, 8025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   centosweb
eab3047a2dde        fab/centosdb        "supervisord -n"    14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       22/tcp, 80/tcp, 8025/tcp               centosdb
```

Trying to connect to my vhosts, I get a database error:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

However, I can connect to centosdb, enter MySQL, and confirm the database is there (i.e.: the db server itself runs fine.)

My understanding so far is that **I'm missing a way to tell MySQL to allow connections from the `web` app instead of the default behavior (connections coming from `localhost`.)** However, I'm confused as to just how to do that.

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273864/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-in-docker-compose) but the latter doesn't contain the specifics I'm looking for.

---

EDIT: the source of the `Dockerfile` for the `db` container.

```
FROM centos:6.9


# Install MySQL (MariaDB)
# Warning: the repo is super slow in my experience (e.g.: 15 min for 191 MB.)
RUN yum -y update
ADD MariaDB.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
RUN yum install -y MariaDB-server MariaDB-client


# Install supervisord
# EPEL = Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux -- used for python
RUN rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install -y python-pip && pip install "pip>=1.4,<1.5" --upgrade
RUN pip install supervisor



##
# START SERVER
# port 22: SSH
# port 80: TCP, HTTP
# port 8025: MailHog UI (web)
##
ADD supervisord-db.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
EXPOSE 22 80 8025
CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]



# MEMO · BUILD THE IMAGE:
# docker build -t fab/centosdb .
```

Comment: Are you pointing to mysql as this? db:3306 (the hostname that `web` see is `db`

Comment: I mean, in the app configuration file

Comment: Please, post `Dockerfile` of your `fab/centosdb` image. Also, make sure that you're pointing to `db` service as @Robert said.

Comment: @Robert: no, I don't think I did that. That's where I'm confused. Where do I do so? `Dockerfile`? YAML?

@kstromeiraos: I updated the question with the Dockerfile in question.

Comment: The first problem is in your application (I guess PHP), in the /var/www/html/ you need to find a configuration file that points to mysql. It seems that you need to change `localhost` to `db`. With that, the error message should change.

Comment: @Robert: thanks, using `links:    - db:3306` (instead of just links:    - db) in `docker-compose.yml`, plus setting the DB host inside of my PHP app to the IP of the container (172.17.0.2, obtained via `docker inspect centosdb`) made it work. The app can now access the db. However, how do I configure this with a hostname? e.g.: db.mysite.dev so I don't have to rely on IP addresses?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Had to add `hostname: db` to the `db` section of the docker compose file.

Answer (score 1):

How is your application configured to talk to MySQL? Instead of `localhost:3306` you need to tell your application to connect to MySQL at `db:3306`. The link sets a DNS name for the MySQL container as `db` and your application should be able to resolve this DNS name to get the correct IP address of the MySQL container.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: We wouldn't know, it is your application. How did you make the connection to MySQL in the first place?

Comment: I thought `links:    - db` in the Docker compose file was enough.

Comment: That makes the database available at `db:3306` inside the container. But the application has to make the connection to `db:3306` instead of `localhost:3306`. Docker does not manage or know about your application configuration.